# Custom TableView Cell Indentation Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewCell in my app and the default indent when the Delete button is present is not happening, below is a screenshot of my settings. Anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Also, here's a shot of the IB properties:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should happen by default, but in your UITableViewDelegate override

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     return YES;
}
```

make sure you aren't doing anything strange in:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and that you are setting the cell's `editingAccessoryType` to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` or `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`

and that you aren't returning `No` from :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: just going over some old posts, there are over 6000 unanswered questions tagged with iphone.